# Iterator Map Issue

Tags: java, collections, iterator, maps

I wanted to take an iterator, which retrieves each record of an Array List(Each object in an array-list have three fields). Now, I wish to send the retrieved record to a function, where I want to populate a Map.

Can somebody suggest how to do that??

```
public class MainClass {

public void func1(int count){
    System.out.println("iterator's record retrieved. Next is to populate"+count+"to the map");
    //populateMap();
    return;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MainClass mc=new MainClass();

    ThreeFields tf1=new ThreeFields();
    ThreeFields tf2=new ThreeFields();
    ThreeFields tf3=new ThreeFields();

    tf1.setField1("A");
    tf1.setField2("B");
    tf1.setField3("C");

    tf2.setField1("D");
    tf2.setField2("E");
    tf2.setField3("F");

    tf3.setField1("G");
    tf3.setField2("H");
    tf3.setField3("I");

    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
    Object al1;
    al.add(tf1);
    al.add(tf2);
    al.add(tf3);

    Iterator i=al.listIterator();

    while(i.hasNext()){
        al1=i.next();


    }

}
```

}

Am not understanding how to use the contents of the retrieved object al1.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I did try. I would like to know the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing a reference of your original list to your method to convert it into a map like this:

```
 Map<Integer, ThreeFields> convert2Map(List<ThreeFields> list) {
      Map<Integer, ThreeFields> map = new HashMap<Integer, ThreeFields>(list.size());
      // Use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap if you want to retain the insertion order
      for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
          map.put(i, list.get(i));
      return map;
 }
```

Also you should use generics when you declare your list in the calling method. So use this form:

```
List<ThreeFields> al = new ArrayList<ThreeFields>();
```

Comment: it would have been good idea to post this code **after** @user1295306 has posted his function trying to do this

Comment: Yes I waited till OP posted some code he attempted on his own.

Comment: thankq soo much for ur time. tried this way. But i have to populate each record at a time. cannot use map and a list together. Tell me if I have to be more clear.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza.. hey.. U can happily stay away if u have some problem with this..

Comment: @user1295306 the problem is that you must explain what have you tried and where you're stuck so people can give you a hand, not just asking how to do thing for you, plus the last comment has a new statement that's not in your question

Comment: @user1295306: Well in that case don't even have a separate method for this. You can very well transfer the code inside my `convert2Map` method into your calling method.

Comment: if i follow the mentioned way, I get a map like this.. field1 value1,value2 value3... field2 .. value1,value2,value3.. I am getting a map where field1 takes all its values, then field2 taking its valuess.. My intention is to get a map like this..  field1 value1, field2 value 2 , field3 value3..

Comment: bcoz i have to take this map, generate a file.. then take the map with second record append this to the file.. soo that my final file is a series of records.

Comment: May I know what are `field1, field2`? I understand `value1,value2 value3` are values in your list. Also if you can post your attempted code in your question I can help you better.

Comment: field 1, field2 field3 are the fields and {A,B,C} {D,E,F} {G,H,I}are the values of these fields. By typecasting the object al1 to the type "ThreeFields", I got the desired result.. thankq.. :)..  @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator myItr  =  myList.iterator();
Item myItem = myItr.next();
myFunction(myItem);
```

is that what you wanted?

You might want to post your attempted code in the future.  People don't like writing your code for you, but rather they like to help you correct it.  That way you learn, and it shows effort on more than just their part.

Comment: I want to populate a map with the retrieved al1 of type Object. I even have a function waiting for it.. ;) ..